# NLP - Word Representations

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a Word representation algorithm, similar to [Word2Vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) and [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).I have been asked to make it more dynamic, such that new words could be added to the vocabulary,and new documents could be submitted to the program even after the representations (vectors) have been created.

The problem is, how do I know if my representation work? How do I know if it actually captures the meaning of each word? How do I compare my representation with other existing vector space models?

As of now, I am doing the following tests to check the quality of my word vectors:

Distance test:

Does the cosine distance between vectors reflect the semantic distance between words?

Analogy test:

Can the representation be used to solve problems like "King is to queen what man is to ________ ", (the answer should be woman)

Picking the odd one out:

Can the vectors be used to pick the odd word in a given list of words. If the input is {"cat","dog","phone"}, the output should be "phone"?

What are the other tests that I should do to check the quality of the vectors? What other tasks are word vectors expected to be capable of doing? Is there a benchmark for vector space models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests sound very reasonable — they are the usual evaluation tasks that are used in research papers to test the quality of word embeddings.

In addition, the website [www.wordvectors.org](http://www.wordvectors.org/) can give you a good idea of how your vectors measure up. It allows you to upload your embeddings, generates plots, gives correlations with word pair similarity rankings, and compares your embeddings with pre-trained vectors from previous research. You can find a more detailed description in the [accompanying paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mfaruqui/papers/acl14-vecdemo.pdf).